# Method of reduction

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm learning about the process of method of reduction and while I understand almost everything, there is one part I cannot figure out.

So the book uses the example:

$$ (1-t^2)\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+2t\frac{dy}{dt}-2y=0 $$

where $y(0)=3$ and $y'(0)=-4$ on the interval $-1<t<1 $

The book says $y_1(t)=t$ is clearly a solution but apparently, I cannot understand the reason why. If anyone can explain, that would be really helpful because most of the problems I've been assigned usually give a solution but just incase, my professor gives a problem that does not have a solution, then I can determine myself.

Comment: You can see $y_=t$ is a solution by inspection.

Comment: If you are asking why $y=t$ is a solution, you can plug it to the equation to check. If you are asking why I know it, it's hard to tell like in many proofs, the author use auxiliary functions which I don't know where they come from. The answer may be just guess and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see $y_=t$ is a solution by inspection. In general fo this type of ode's you need to use more general techniques ([Frobenius method](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=FPgVVfHkBsaAqQXo2ICICQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=frobenius)). To use reduction of order method assume your solution to have the form

$$ y_2(t)=y_1(t)u(t) = t u(t)  $$

and substitute back in the ode and then solve the resulting ode in $u(t)$.